# Generic way to cast union to Maybe of its component types

Tags: generics, elm

I have a union type that looks like this:

```
type User
    = Admin ComplicatedAdminRecord
    . . .
    | NormalUser ComplicatedUserRecord
```

I'm looking for a *generic* way to filter a `List User` into (possibly empty) `List`s of the union's component types.

What I have *works*, but it's horrible and the amount of copypasta code is linear in the number of types I'm trying to filter on. It looks like this:

```
asMaybeAdmin : User -> Maybe ComplicatedAdminRecord
asMaybeAdmin user =
    case user of
        Admin adminUser ->
            Just adminUser

        _ ->
            Nothing

onlyAdmins =
    List.filterMap asMaybeAdmin users
```

This is fine if you only have one type that you're trying to filter for, but having to write a new `asMaybe<Type>` for each component type is a lot of repetition that I feel like I should be able to write generically.

Comment: This looks like a higher-level problem with how you've structured your data model. I'd look into addressing that instead.

Comment: `User` here is a stand-in for our domain-specific event type... suppose with me for a moment that there's a good reason to have all events in a single "stream," so to speak (or at least enough legacy code on the back-end that splitting apart whole API isn't an option).

Comment: I've been using Elm a long time and have code exactly like this. It causes no problems whatsoever. You write it once (per type) and it's done. What SPECIFIC and SERIOUS problems does it cause for you? Sounds like the problem is a feeling that you could write it with less code.

Comment: It mostly just feels wrong to copy & paste the implementation of `toMaybe<Whatever>` a dozen times, changing only the type each time. That's... a lot of code to have to wade through for something so trivial. ‍♂️

Comment: @s3cur3 I understand. The "Elm culture" is one which focuses on the hard problems and actively avoids "fixing" things which are not hard problems. Because often fixating on the latter creates its own problems and tradeoffs. You will therefore end up with code that repeats **a pattern**, but at least it's explicit, safe, compiles quickly, and will likely never cause serious problems down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [auto-generate variant helpers](https://dark.elm.dmy.fr/packages/lue-bird/elm-review-missing-record-field-lens/latest/VariantHelper-GenerateUsed) via [`elm-review`](https://dark.elm.dmy.fr/packages/jfmengels/elm-review/latest/).

Out of the box, you can generate "prisms" (these combine multiple helpers: access, alter, name)

- [`erlandsona/elm-accessors`](https://dark.elm.dmy.fr/packages/erlandsona/elm-accessors/latest/)
- [`bChiquet/elm-accessors`](https://dark.elm.dmy.fr/packages/bChiquet/elm-accessors/latest/)

but implementing simpler helpers is also possible! ↓ implements `toVariant` access functions

- try it out

  ```bash
  elm-review --template lue-bird/elm-review-missing-record-field-lens/example/variant-helpers-simple
  ```
- [source code](https://github.com/lue-bird/elm-review-missing-record-field-lens/blob/2.0.1/preview/variant-helpers-simple/src/ReviewConfig.elm)

There are similar projects that you might wanna look at but don't offer variant accessing, yet:

- [`MartinSStewart/elm-review-todo-it-for-me`](https://github.com/MartinSStewart/elm-review-todo-it-for-me)
- [`lue-bird/generate-elm`](https://github.com/lue-bird/generate-elm)